# Swift 2 AirPrint on iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, macos, swift2, sift, airprint

How can i print a page in Swift for iOS and OSX like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I'll be very happy if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish someone would answer questions like this. There is no way to print HTML markup on macOS. It's so annoying why Apple didn't finish their work....